# Deploying LiteDB

Tags: vb.net, winforms, setup-deployment, litedb

I am in the process of building a VS2013 setup project to deploy a Winforms application that uses a LiteDB database to a several Windows 7 Workstations. Different users can login to the workstation.  The application needs R/W access to the database.  Each application is self-contained so a centralized database is not needed.  I am not sure which folder to deploy the database file.  Can this file be deployed to the ProgramData folder?  I am currently considering deploying to C:\Users\Public.

Comment: `Can this file be deployed to the ProgramData folder`, ***yes it can***. One option as well is put it in `C:\users\public` which can be accessed by any and all users as you already stated in your question.